# Why I'm getting only parent class property & method while parent class object is initiating with child class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose I've following two class & their relationship as shown in below.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int parentID { get; set; }
}
public class Child : Parent
{
    public string childId { get; set; }
}
```

In the main method, while I'm creating a parent class object with a child class instance that time I can only access or see the parent class property as follows.

[image]

but in runtime, I can see the property from both classes is exists as follows.

[image]

I'm not getting the logic on the mentioned scenario. Please let me clear on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about the logic but rather Intellisense vs a debugger. `pParent.`  at design time and Intellisense acting against a variable declared as `Parent`. But at runtime, the debugger looks inside actual object, which is `Child` as per

```
Parent pParent = new Child();
```

And this assignment is legal because `Child` derived from `Parent`. But at design time you don't have a real object. So what do you do? - cast

```
Child castFromParent = (Child)pParent;
Console.WriteLine(castFromParent.childId); // <-- no design time issues
```

Basically, it comes down to Compilation vs runtime Polymorphism. 2 different things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, But here you're forcefully casting pParent to Child type. I've already worked on it. But my concern is why I'm not getting this at compile time.

Comment: @RajuAhmed What do you mean, "my concern"?  **^^** the answer above explains exactly what is your **confusion** rather than concern **^^**. You're confusing design time compilation and runtime polymorphism. And the `cast` is not a solution but explanation

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the *compile* time type of a reference and the *runtime* type of the object its pointing to can be two completely different things.

Obviously both types must be related (assignment compatibility) but the distinction is still there and its important you understand it:

```
object myString = "Hello";
```

the compile time type of the *variable* `myString` is `System.Object`. But when you run the code, the runtime type of the object stored in `myString` is `System.String`.

Intellisense can only reason about *compile* time types while the debugger can reason about the *runtime* type of objects. That is why your code editor will only show members of the compile time type while editing where as the debugger will show you the members of the runtime object.